# Eclipse juno getting error during build

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-juno

I am getting error after building though it is showing build success. Its showing error "Errors running builder 'Faceted Project Validation Builder' on [projectname]" and "Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.project.facet.IJ2EEFacetConstants".
How to resolve this? This is in eclipse juno.
I tried with the solutions mentioned in similar question[properties-->project facets].But still my issue exist.

Comment: There are other questions in SO that address both error messages, if you don't indicate how the solutions don't work for you, it should be marked as duplicate IMO

Comment: I tried checking the properties----> project facets as mentioned in the comments of that question. But still facing the same issue.